# Can I exclude specific controllers from the standard tab traversal?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I've made a custom dialog that contains a series of text controls. Every text control has a couple of buttons beside them for adding specific values more conveniently. I don't want these buttons to receive focus when the user it tab traversing through the dialog, since the user, in most cases, won't need to use the buttons.

Is there any convenient way to exclude specific controllers from the standard tab traversal?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to prevent a button from being focused with the keyboard is to derive from `wx.lib.buttons.GenButton` or `wx.lib.buttons.ThemedGenButton` which are based on `wx.PyControl` that supports overriding of `AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard()`:

```
class NoFocusButton(wx.lib.buttons.ThemedGenButton):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, label=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0, validator=wx.DefaultValidator, name=wx.ButtonNameStr):
        wx.lib.buttons.ThemedGenButton.__init__(self,parent,id,label,pos,size,style,validator,name)
    def AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard(self):
        return False # does not accept focus
```

---

For more complex navigation rules or controls, you could handle `wx.EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY` and manage the navigation yourself. To get the list of windows to navigate, you can use `self.GetChildren()`. The index of the the currently focused window in the `wx.WindowList` can be obtained through `.index(mywindow)`.
With that information, you can navigate through the list whenever the user presses the "navigation key" and set the focus to the next applicable control, skipping those that you don't want to focus.

To make navigating through the list easier, you could create a generator:

```
def CycleList(thelist,index,forward):
    for unused in range(len(thelist)): # cycle through the list ONCE
        if forward:
            index = index+1 if index+1 < len(thelist) else 0
        else:
            index = index-1 if index-1 >= 0 else len(thelist)-1
        yield thelist[index]
```

In the dialog, handle `wx.EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY`:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY, self.OnNavigationKey)
```

```
def OnNavigationKey(self,event):
    children = self.GetChildren() # list of child windows
    focused = self.FindFocus()    # current focus

    # avoid accessing elements that do not exist
    if not focused or focused not in children:
        event.Skip() # use default behavior
        return

    index = children.index(focused)

    for child in CycleList(children,index,event.GetDirection()):
        # default behavior:
        if child.AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard():
            child.SetFocus()
            return
```

The example above emulates the default behavior: it cycles through focusable controls (skipping unfocusable controls like static texts).
You could expand the check to exclude specific controls or create a custom button class that implements `AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard` returning False.

**NOTE:** While `wx.PyWindow`, `wx.PyPanel` and `wx.PyControl` implement the mechanism to allow overriding of `AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard`, the standard wxPython controls **do not**.
However, handling `wx.EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY` and checking `AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard` on the python side will access the actual python object which will invoke the overridden method.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using C++ this problem has a straightforward solution as described in the remainder of this answer.  In wxPython it seems you cannot specialize wxWidgets classes - which seems to me a fatal snag.

You could create a specialization of the button control which will be left out of the tab traversal by overriding AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard() to return FALSE.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a2370bdd3ab08e7ef3c7555c6aa8301b8

The following C++ code works fine: focus jumps from the first to the third button when tab is pressed

```
class cNoTabButton : public wxButton
{
public:
    cNoTabButton(wxWindow *parent,
             wxWindowID id,
             const wxString& label = wxEmptyString,
             const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
             const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
             long style = 0 )
             : wxButton(parent,id,label,pos,size,style)
    {}
    bool AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard() const { 
        return false;
    }
};

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    // set the frame icon
    SetIcon(wxICON(sample));

    wxPanel * panel = new wxPanel(this,-1,wxPoint(0,0),wxSize(500,500));

    new wxButton(panel,-1,"TabPlease",wxPoint(20,20));
    new cNoTabButton(panel,-1,"NoTabThanks",wxPoint(100,20));
    new wxButton(panel,-1,"OKWithMe",wxPoint(200,20));


}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with wxPython. ([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7dKniVXg))

Comment: I am no python expert, so I dunno why your code doesn't work.  Are you sure that is all you need to specialize a control?  Where is your constructor?  I have posted working C++ code.

Comment: This simply doesn't work in Python because overriding functions such as this has no effect. The c++ libraries were never calling this function to begin with.

Comment: It's not an issue with Python, it has to do with wxPython. If wxPython was written in pure Python then overriding the classes would work just fine, but it isn't. Method calls on wxWidgets objects like `Button` from Python executes actual C++ code, but method calls from wxWidgets, such as the code that manages tab traversal, can't call Python methods - so there's no use in trying to override C++ functions from Python. wxPython has a defined a few Python version of classes, e.g. `PyWindow` and `PyPanel` that supports method overriding from Python, but the button control isn't one of them.

Comment: That makes sense.  +1.  I over-ride wxWidgets classes all the time to include special behaviour.  I was wondering if I should learn wxpython - now I will not bother.  Thanks for saving me wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution but one way to do this is actually to delay your control's getting the focus back by half a second.

Your main window will get focus back and buttons still work. I use it because I want my main windows to handle all key presses but still to contain buttons on it that are used with the mouse.

So you bind your KILL_FOCUS event in the control that is supposed to preserve the focus and you create a list of controls that cannot get the focus from it.

First a helper function to get all children:

```
def GetAllChildren(control):
    children = []
    for c in control.GetChildren():
        children.append(c)
        children += GetAllChildren(c)
    return children
```

In my case I want all the children of the window to not get focus

```
self.not_allowed_focus = GetAllChildren(self)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.OnKillFocus)
```

In my KILL FOCUS handler I ask for the focus back after half a second

```
def OnKillFocus(self,evt):
    print "OnKillFocus"
    win = evt.GetWindow()
    if win in self.not_allowed_focus:
        wx.CallLater(500,self.SetFocus)
```